# Taskwarrior with Timewarrior - cannot overlap intervals

Tags: bash, vim, gtd

I have a setup with VimWiki, TaskWarrior/TimeWarrior and TaskWiki.
Yesterday I observed, that some task wheren't tracked, because I couldn't get a `timew summary` of it.

When I started those task from TaskWarrior directly I got the message:
`You cannot overlap intervals. Correct the start/end time, or specify the :adjust hint.` 
The task was started correctly by TaskWarrior (I could see it in the list as "active") but was NOT recognized by TimeWarrior in any way.

I tried a few things, but I can't find unpropper intervals anywhere and I can't find Information on how to use ":adjust" with TASKwarrior.

The examplary task:

```
Name          Value                                 
ID            10
Description   task review and push                  
Status        Pending
Entered       2018-08-21 11:55:09 (20h)             
Start         2018-08-22 08:09:31
Last modified 2018-08-22 08:09:31 (1min)            
Tags          w daily
Virtual tags  ACTIVE PENDING READY TAGGED UNBLOCKED 
UUID          afe4be48-aed6-4d1f-aba7-d748bf368868
Urgency        4.9                                  

    active      1 *    4 =      4
    tags      0.9 *    1 =    0.9
                           ------
                              4.9

Date                Modification                                                                  
2018-08-21 11:55:41 Tags set to 'w,daily'.
2018-08-21 16:10:09 Start set to '2018-08-21 16:10:09'.                                           
2018-08-21 16:25:40 Description changed from 'task review and push !!' to 'task review and push'.
2018-08-21 16:25:41 Start deleted (duration: PT15M32S).                                           
2018-08-21 16:25:42 Start set to '2018-08-21 16:25:42'.
2018-08-21 16:25:58 Start deleted (duration: PT16S).
```

Can someone please tell me what it has to do with the "cannot overlap"-message and how to resolve it, please.

Answer (score 4):

I know this issue is so old, it's probably solved, but for reference:

I ran into a similar problem. I'm not sure what caused it, but I think that it happened because I forgot to stop the time-tracking at some point. Timewarrior created lots of tracked days in the future.
I was able to find the IDs of the days in the future by getting the tasks for the whole year

`timew summary :year :id`

and then deleting the tasks in the future with

`timew delete @1 @2` (or whatever IDs apply)

After the deletion tasks can be tracked normally again.